# mv misbehaves in shell script

Tags: shell-script, command-line, mv

I have the following folder structure:

*/backup*

*/backup/copy.sh*

*/backup/archive/*

*/backup/20160405_logs/*

*/backup/20160405_logs/sql.log*

*/backup/20160405_logs/bak.log*

I want to move the folder *20160405_logs* into */backup/archive/*. If I run `mv /backup/20160405_logs /backup/archive` from the CLI (manually type and run) it works perfectly. However, if I run that command from *copy.sh* I get the following error for each file within *20160405_logs*:

`copy.sh: line x: file_path: No such file or directory` where is x is an **incorrect** line number for `mv` call in *copy.sh*.

All the files and their parent folder are moved though. So it's not like the move is failing...

What am I missing!?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Sounds a bit like Windows/ UNIX file formatting of copy.sh

Comment: how does your script `copy.sh` exactly look like?

Comment: That command is part of a longer backup script. There are `echo`'s that output to the CLI and some that print to log files. This might explain the incorrect line numbers.

That said, `mv` command is written as stated above.

I updated my question - I forgot to mention that the move is successful, despite the errors...

Comment: @JeffSchaller this is being executed on a DreamHost private server.

Comment: if line x is not the line number for the mv command, maybe you could show us line x and/or the line with "file_path" in it?

Comment: @JeffSchaller if there was a badge for nitwits I'd get it. I'll post an answer now, explaining what's happening *sob*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jeff Schallers' second comment pointed me in the right direction.

My backup script looks like this:

`tar source_folder dest_file >> /backup/20160405_logs/bak.log
mv /backup/20160405_logs /backup/archive
echo "Backup complete" >> /backup/20160405_logs /backup/archive`

The missing files that are being reported are log files that I am trying to write to after I run the `mv` command.

As mentioned in my comment above, if there were a badge for nitwits, I'd own one!

Sorry for wasting everyone's time.